# how a cpp function should return "-1" as char*?

Tags: c++, char

For a problem statement, there is a case in which a cpp function returning `char*` needs to `return` value as `-1`. How to return char* with negative integer value?

Sample pseudo-code where the function is decrypting the `mystring` and returning a character at given `index` and if not found should return `-1`:

```
char * decrypt(char *mystring, int index){.........................
//code for decrypt mystring
if (index is valid after decryption)
     return valid value
else 
     return '-1';
}
```

In the above block of code how to return '-1' compatible to  char *

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If you want to return an "invalid pointer" return a `nullptr`

Comment: `-1` is not a char, if you turn your compiler warnings on, it will show you that multiple-character char literals are not allowed. You could return "-1" if you change the return value to `const char*` but that is really terrible.

Comment: @UnholySheep This is the specific case and the expectation is to return "-1" if not found

Comment: Then you can follow Quimby's advice, although it's still a terrible requirement and doesn't make sense

Comment: @Quimby Multicharacter literals are allowed by the standard, but the support is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Quimby cannot change the signature of the function to const char*

Comment: @NotAProgrammer Did not know that, thanks, that seems like another thing unnecessarily left undefined.

Comment: @SmrutiPrayag Well, then you will have to return a dynamically allocated string, that's pretty unsafe thing to do.

Comment: @Quimby Yes agree, thats unsafe. I have tried allocating dynamically as well but did not work , it prints only "-" and not complete  "-1". do you have sample code?

Comment: The problem description, "returning a character at given index", says that the function should return exactly one character - `decrypted_string[index]` - not a pointer. If the description is correct, the result type should be `char`.

Comment: @SmrutiPrayag Well, if you treat the result as `char`, it will print "-" just. In that case you really have badly designed interface, as others have said too.

Comment: @SmrutiPrayag If your goal is to print `"-1"` and not a `-1` as a pointer, just change `'-1'` to `"-1"`. In C++ `' '` is for `char` and `" "` is for `char*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if not found should return -1:

This is a bad design. Pointers have a conventional way to represent a value that doesn't point to anything: The null pointer. A more conventional design is to return `nullptr` when result is not found.

If you use an arbitrary value such as -1, it would be quite difficult for the caller to determine that result was not found.

---

> How to return char* with negative integer value?

Example (but keep in mind that this is a bad design):

```
std::intptr_t negative = -1;
return reinterpret_cast<char*>(negative);
```

---

> and returning a character at

Your function contradicts your description. The function doesn't return a character; it returns a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you have std::optional (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to suit such cases (although you will certainly need more experience).

Comment: Optional is not by definition the best tool for the job. It all depends on who you want to own the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can return '#' to return -1 in character returned function in cpp
`return '#';`.

```cpp
char func() { return '#'; }
```